# Using pear with PHPUnit, eclipse sees PHPUnit but not Mockery

Tags: eclipse, phpunit, pear, mockery

I have installed Pear and used Pear to install PHPUnit and Mockery.
I have PHPUnit running successfully in elipse (the pear directory is configured as an include path in the project).

I would like to use Mockery but eclipse keeps giving me this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'deepend\Mockery' not found`

I followed the advice here: http://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php/Configure_Eclipse_for_PHPUnit
but am not sure how to load the library.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
use \Mockery as m;

define('BASEPATH', (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../sys'));

require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../models/products_model_composed.php');

class ProductsModelTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { 
    private $products;
    private $mock_ci_model;


public function setUp(){
    $this->products = new products_model_composed();
    $this->define_ci_mock();
    $this->products->__set('ci_model', $this->mock_ci_model);
}

private function define_ci_mock(){
    $ci = m::mock('CI_Model');
    $ci->shouldReceive('ee')->once()->andReturn($this);
}
```

See first line in function define_ci_mock.  This is where Mockery is called but not found.
Can you point me in the right direction?
I've installed Mockery 0.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  Just when I had given up for the day I found the answer!

A bootstrap file needs to be run first with these parameters:

```
require_once 'Mockery/Loader.php';
require_once 'Hamcrest/Hamcrest.php';
$loader = new \Mockery\Loader;
$loader->register();
```

See https://github.com/padraic/mockery/blob/master/README.markdown

> Mockery ships with an autoloader so you don't need to litter your tests with require_once() calls. To use it, ensure Mockery is on your include_path and add the following to your test suite's Bootstrap.php or TestHelper.php file: